# How to get in point geometry to pinpoint accurately where geometries have mistakes?

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, sql, geometry

Basically I have some line and some polygon tables which have invalid some geometries and apparently PostgreSQL returns errors when trying to return reports which rely on intersecting these features

To help people fix these mistakes I'm trying to come up with a view which points out the mistakes.

I could easily just do:

```
    SELECT id,name,geometry 
    FROM   polygontable  
    WHERE  ST_IsValid(geometry) is not true
```

The problem is that people will have to check the entire polygon when it's probably a single node that is wrong.

How to actually return the point location of the mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`ST_IsValidDetail`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsValidDetail.html):

```
SELECT rs.reason,
       ST_AsText(rs.location) AS location
FROM   <table>,
       LATERAL ST_IsValidDetail(geom) AS rs
WHERE  NOT ST_IsValid(geom)
;
```

Comment: Chances are you can fix many cases with `ST_MakeValid` in an `UPDATE`. There is no way to avoid errors if invalidity is 2nd degree, i.e. introduced during a C library operation. I feel silly pointing you to this, but nothing keeps you from having an index on `ST_IsValid`...

Comment: Thanks, this worked! actually I will make a trigger to stop people from creating invalid geometries but this is needed. What I can observe is that when there are too few points in lines, I cant see these on the map. works fine for polygons tho. Ive tried makevalid but it caused geometrycollections which made the layer unavailable on qgis... I'll just let people fix their own poop

Comment: Lol, fair enough. But PostGIS shouldn't let you create LineStrings with less than 2 vertices in the first place, though, and `ST_IsValid` should report `FALSE` on those with *too few points*, which would include e.g. `LINESTRING(0 0, 0 0)` (having a single, repeated point) , and at least in that case `ST_IsValidDetail` shows `POINT(0 0)`.